# Is there a good tutorial on how to use bitcoinjs exit nodes?

Tags: development, bitcoinjs

[The documentation](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/node-bitcoin-exit/wiki/REST-API) that I found seems to contain info about specific API calls, but no top level explaination/example.

Where can I find a practical concise example of using exit nodes?

I'd like to query transactions (say ... poll to see all latest transaction to a specific address), and submit a new transaction.

Comment: Might be worth pointing Stefan at this question and see if he'll answer.

Comment: Have you gotten it to install? When I run `npm install`, I get all sorts of errors

Comment: @Shamoon - I haven't tried too much, sorry - do post here if you have more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with the included [test package](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib/tree/master/test) first. Then check the dependent projects.